# Mathtools' showonlyrefs fails with subequations

Tags: mathtools, subequations

For the code

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:sub}
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\text{d}b_1}{\text{d}z} - \im\beta_1b_1 = C_{12}b_2,\\
  \frac{\text{d}b_2}{\text{d}z} - \im\beta_2b_2 = C_{21}b_1.
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

with `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true,showmanualtags=true}`, the `\eqref` correctly references the equation group number, however the equations themselves appear in the document without numbers (so the previous equation is, say (2.7), the following one is (2.9) and no numbers 2.8a and 2.8b). Is it to be expected? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround might be to label the two inner equations and use `\noeqref` to silently reference them. At the moment `showonlytags` does not take subequations into account, and might be difficult to implement.

Here is how `showonlyrefs` works. `\eqref` sets a special marker `label` to mark a given label referred to. `mathtools` changes the manner in which the equation numbers are typeset to see if the local label has been marked. If not it is not typeset.

The problem here is that the outer label will never be seen by the eq number typesetter within the gather.

EDIT: this works. BTW: next time please post a minimal example not a sniplet, I have no idea what `\im` is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true,showmanualtags=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:sub}
  \noeqref{eq:1,eq:2}
  \begin{gather}
    \frac{\text{d}b_1}{\text{d}z} - \beta_1b_1 = C_{12}b_2,\label{eq:1}\\
    \frac{\text{d}b_2}{\text{d}z} - \beta_2b_2 = C_{21}b_1.\label{eq:2}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\eqref{eq:sub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please give a good example? I do not understand how to use the `\noeqref`. Probably I put it in the wrong place. The documentation refers to `\nocite`, but a similar use doesn't help here.

Comment: `\noeqref{labelname}` just place it somewhere in your document, e.g. within the `subequations` before the `gather`, this will mark them as have been refered to. And you of course have to label each equation

Comment: OK, I was trying `\noeqref{eq:sub}`. Thanks for the example and sorry about `\im`.